# How to provide external link using echo in php?

Tags: php, sql, echo

I am trying to store some link in database, for example `www.google.com`. Lets say after pulling the value from database I stored it in `$url`. Now, I am trying to set the link by doing

```
echo "<a href=$url>link</a>"
```

Now, the problem - whenever I click on the link the links goes to `www.mydomain.com/www.google.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `http://` to the beggining of the link. EG:

```
 echo "http://$url";
```

:)

Comment: Or store the "http://" as part of the string in the database. This is probably preferred, since you'll occasionally need to differentiate between http and https. (Or mailto: or tel: or whatever.)

Comment: Actually, I think I'd just do a string check on the link first. If it already starts with a protocol indicator, then echo it as is, else prepend http:// to it. Then you can store them either way.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you're using? It should work providing `$url` is prefixed with `http://`

Answer (score 2):

This might depend on the browser, but links are always relative and outbound links should include the correct `http` or `https` protocol specification.